# xslt 2.0 sort elements by number

Tags: sorting, xslt

I have the below input XML,
for some reason my xslt is not able to sort it.
please advice.
appreciate your insights.
this is the full XML 
......................................................

I want to sort the G_SHL segment with its content based on D_628 field.

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LIST>
    <S_ISA>
        <D_I01>00</D_I01>
        <D_I02/>
        <D_I03>00</D_I03>
        <D_I04/>
        <D_I05>01</D_I05>
        <D_I06></D_I06>
        <D_I05_2>ZZ</D_I05_2>
        <D_I07></D_I07>
        <D_I08>160427</D_I08>
        <D_I09>1106</D_I09>
        <D_I10>U</D_I10>
        <D_I11>00401</D_I11>
        <D_I12>000000001</D_I12>
        <D_I13>0</D_I13>
        <D_I14/>
        <D_I15>&gt;</D_I15>
        <S_GS>
            <D_479>SH</D_479>
            <D_142></D_142>
            <D_124></D_124>
            <D_373>20160427</D_373>
            <D_337>1106</D_337>
            <D_28>1</D_28>
            <D_455>X</D_455>
            <D_480>004010</D_480>
            <S_ST>
                <D_143>856</D_143>
                <D_329>0001</D_329>
                <S_BSN>
                    <D_353>00</D_353>
                    <D_396>0081664420</D_396>
                    <D_373>20160426</D_373>
                    <D_337>1347</D_337>
                    <D_1005>0001</D_1005>
                </S_BSN>
                <G_SHL>
                    <S_HL>
                        <D_628>0000001</D_628>
                        <D_734>0000000</D_734>
                        <D_735>S</D_735>
                        <S_PRF>
                            <D_324>SITT10-1447195769627</D_324>
                            <D_328>SITT10-1447195769627</D_328>
                        </S_PRF>
                        <S_MEA>
                            <D_737>PD</D_737>
                            <D_738>G</D_738>
                            <D_739>0.081</D_739>
                            <C_C001>
                                <D_355>KG</D_355>
                            </C_C001>
                        </S_MEA>
                        <S_TD1>
                            <D_103>PKG</D_103>
                            <D_80>00002</D_80>
                            <D_187>G</D_187>
                            <D_81>00000.18</D_81>
                            <D_355>LB</D_355>
                        </S_TD1>
                        <S_TD5>
                            <D_133>O</D_133>
                            <D_66>2</D_66>
                            <D_368>CC</D_368>
                        </S_TD5>
                        <S_REF>
                            <D_128>WH</D_128>
                            <D_127>WH:</D_127>
                        </S_REF>
                        <S_REF>
                            <D_128>RN</D_128>
                            <D_127>RN:</D_127>
                        </S_REF>
                        <S_DTM>
                            <D_374>011</D_374>
                            <D_373>20160414</D_373>
                        </S_DTM>
                        <G_SN1>
                            <S_N1>
                                <D_98>ST</D_98>
                                <D_93>C3333</D_93>
                                <S_N3>
                                    <D_166>TEST</D_166>
                                </S_N3>
                                <S_N4>
                                    <D_19>TEST</D_19>
                                    <D_116>12345</D_116>
                                    <D_26>US</D_26>
                                </S_N4>
                            </S_N1>
                        </G_SN1>
                    </S_HL>
                </G_SHL>
                <G_SHL>
                    <S_HL>
                        <D_628>0000002</D_628>
                        <D_734>0000001</D_734>
                        <D_735>O</D_735>
                        <S_MAN>
                            <D_88>CP</D_88>
                            <D_87></D_87>
                        </S_MAN>
                    </S_HL>
                </G_SHL>
                <G_SHL>
                    <S_HL>
                        <D_628>0000003</D_628>
                        <D_734>0000002</D_734>
                        <D_735>P</D_735>
                    </S_HL>
                </G_SHL>
                <G_SHL>
                    <S_HL>
                        <D_628>0000005</D_628>
                        <D_734>0000002</D_734>
                        <D_735>P</D_735>
                    </S_HL>
                </G_SHL>
                <G_SHL>
                    <S_HL>
                        <D_628>0000004</D_628>
                        <D_734>0000003</D_734>
                        <D_735>I</D_735>
                        <S_LIN>
                            <D_350>000010</D_350>
                            <D_235>SK</D_235>
                            <D_234></D_234>
                            <D_235_2>BP</D_235_2>
                            <D_234_2></D_234_2>
                        </S_LIN>
                        <S_SN1>
                            <D_350></D_350>
                            <D_382>2.000</D_382>
                            <D_355>EA</D_355>
                            <D_668>AC</D_668>
                        </S_SN1>
                    </S_HL>
                </G_SHL>
                <G_SHL>
                    <S_HL>
                        <D_628>0000006</D_628>
                        <D_734>0000005</D_734>
                        <D_735>I</D_735>
                        <S_LIN>
                            <D_350>000020</D_350>
                            <D_235></D_235>
                            <D_234></D_234>
                            <D_235_2>BP</D_235_2>
                            <D_234_2></D_234_2>
                        </S_LIN>
                        <S_SN1>
                            <D_382>1.000</D_382>
                            <D_355>EA</D_355>
                            <D_668>AC</D_668>
                        </S_SN1>
                    </S_HL>
                </G_SHL>
                <S_CTT>
                    <D_354>1</D_354>
                </S_CTT>
                <S_SE>
                    <D_96>[]</D_96>
                    <D_329>0001</D_329>
                </S_SE>
            </S_ST>
            <S_GE>
                <D_97>0</D_97>
                <D_28>1</D_28>
            </S_GE>
        </S_GS>
        <S_IEA>
            <D_I16>01</D_I16>
            <D_I12>000000001</D_I12>
        </S_IEA>
    </S_ISA>
</LIST>`
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the XML and XSLT samples are code, rather than images. Thank you.

Comment: I don't find any `S_HL` in your input sample, so what should `match="/LIST/S_ISA/S_GS/S_ST/G_SHL/S_HL"` achieve?

Comment: sorry about that.loaded a new one. please note that the related element of <D_628>0000005</D_628>  is out of place

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/LIST/S_ISA/S_GS/S_ST">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="G_SHL">
       <xsl:sort select="S_HL/D_628" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
     </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

I can't verify the path `/LIST/S_ISA/S_GS/S_ST` but assume you have those ancestor elements in your real XML.

If there can be sibling elements you want to keep in their original input position then one way in XSLT 2.0 is to first identify the adjacent elements you want to sort with `for-each-group group-adjacent`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/LIST/S_ISA/S_GS/S_ST">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="boolean(self::G_SHL)">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                            <xsl:sort select="S_HL/D_628" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
                        </xsl:apply-templates>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"></xsl:apply-templates>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: few semantic changes and worked!! can you explain why this seleciton of "template match" XPATH  values and "sort" worked? what is the logic? thanks for your help! much appreciated

Comment: If you want to sort the `G_SHL` elements then the usual way is to do that in a template for the parent element where you copy the parent and then process the child elements in the desired order, using a sort expression for the value you want to sort by.

Comment: I have attached this step to the full integration process and apperently the template:match of "/LIST/S_ISA/S_GS/S_ST"  is dropping other fields under the S_ST before getting to the first G_SHL. how can I still keep thous fields?

Comment: You will need to edit your question and show small but complete representatives sample of XML input and wanted output. It is not obvious which order you might want in the result if the `G_SHL` can have other sibling elements.

Comment: @Nimrod.G, I have added an enhanced sample that might help. If not, then you need to explain which result you want.